# Application of RSA cryptosystem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I am currently studying for an exam and attempting the following past exam question:

Let $N$ be the product of two distinct odd prime numbers $p$ and $q$ which are both congruent
to $3\pmod 4$. Suppose further that $(p-1)(q-1)$ is not divisible by $3$. Show that there do
not exist two distinct messages which are interchanged by RSA encryption using the public
key $(N, 3)$. (Hint: You may assume that if $r$ is a prime number congruent to $3\pmod 4$ then
$-1$ is not a square in $\mathbb{Z}_r$.)

Unfortunately, I am unable to tackle it really or see the direction I am aiming for. 
In particular, what would the relevance of $p,q$ being congruent to $3\pmod4$ be? As far as I am aware this implies something about them being prime but as we were already given previously that they are both distinct and prime, what was the purpose of this congruence?

Also, when asked to show that no two distinct messages can be interchanged using the encryption, I suppose I am trying to show there exist no solutions $$m^3 = n^3, m\neq n. $$

However, I don't see how to make use of the hint. 
Just trialling things:

Say we work in $\pmod p$
$$m^3 \equiv n^3 \implies m^3-n^3 \equiv 0.  $$

I think I should factorise this and find a term with squares involved and then potentially make use of the hint but I'm not sure really...

Any points in the right direction are greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:

Following on new advice in the comments I have attempted the following;

Since the messages are *interchanged* this actually means that $E(m)=n$ and $E(n)=m$.

So lets say we are working in $\pmod p$. We then have $$m^3 \equiv n ,  n^3 \equiv m.$$

My approach would be to treat these as simultaneous equations.

$m^3-n=0$

$n^3-m=0$

Multiplying the second equation by $m^2$ and adding the two equations together we find $$ n(m^2-1)=0.$$ Of course the possible solutions are: 
$n=0, m^2-1=0.$
We see that $n=0$ cannot be a solution as that would imply $m = 0$ from our equation $n^3-m=0$.
So, let's say our solution is $m^2-1=0$, this give us the possible values $m=1,-1.$ Using the hint we can exclude $m=-1$ as a possible solution, which then leaves us with $m=1$.

However, from our equation $m^3-n=0$ this would imply $1-n=0 \implies n=1$ but as $m \neq n$ this cannot be true.

Hence there are NO solutions in $\pmod p$, the same argument can be used for $\pmod q$ thus $0\times0=0$ so there are no solutions in $\pmod N$ implying that there are no two distinct messages that could be interchanged by this system.

Comment: The exam for the crytology course was encoded. :)

Comment: $m^3 = n^3 \bmod{N}$ for $m \neq n$ means that two messages have the same encryption, and this cannot happen as decryption is unique. I think the questions means we cannot have  $m \neq n \in \mathbb{Z}_N$ such that $E(m) = n$ and $E(n) = m$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Thank you for the response, this question has been on my mind all evening! What you say makes more sensewhen saying two separate messages are interchanged. In which case, would I be correct in saying that I'd need to find solutions for $m^3 \equiv n\pmod N$ ? And of course show that there are no solutions

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I have updated my post with a possible solution, if you could perhaps give me some feedback I'd really appreciate it!

Comment: $n(m^2 -1) = 0$ modulo $N$ does not mean $n = 0$ or $m^2- 1= 0$ modulo $N$. This holds in a field, not in $\mathbb{Z}_N$. E.g. $n$ could be a multiple of $p$ while $m^2 -1$ could  be a multiple of $q$... You have to reason more carefully.